# Null is sorted first in arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I haven't been able to find anything on this online, so any help would be appreciated.  In my todo list app, I have an array that is 14 elements large.  When any elements are added to the array, I use Array.Sort, then print all elements of the array.  However, the array is sorted with the empty cells first.

For example, if you add "Programming is hard" to cell 0, then array.sort, the method used to print the array will put the string into cell 13, causing the todo list to look weird.

So, how do you use the Array.Sort method to put empty cells last?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Use Array.Sort(Array, IComparer) to use a custom comparer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why not use an ArrayList instead? `List<String> toDoList = new List<String>();` That can be sorted, and doesn't have a fixed size like arrays do.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the overload for Array.Sort() that takes a comparer function.

```
Array.Sort(arr, (a, b) => a == null ? 1 : b == null ? -1 : a.CompareTo(b));
```

Take a look at the documentation for [`IComparer<T>.Compare(T,T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the expectations on what this function you pass in should return.

When you use `Array.Sort(Array)`, the sort calls the default comparer, which for `string`s happens to sort null values first. The `Array.Sort<T>(T[], Comparer<T>)` allows you to customize the comparison behavior.

The lambda we pass in, `(a, b) => a == null ? 1 : b == null ? -1 : a.CompareTo(b))`, follows this path:

1. If `a == null`, return greater than 1 since our comparison deems `null` as less than anything,
2. Else if `b == null`, return less than 1 since our comparison deems `null` as less than anything,
3. Else, defer to the default comparison implementation for `string`..

---

Alternatively if you just don't want to deal with null values, consider filtering them out:

```
arr.Where(s => s != null);
```

or replacing them with some sensible value,

```
arr.Select(s => s == null ? "Invalid task" : s);
```

as depends on your needs.

Comment: Just an observation... if the OP does not understand what is happening with the Array in the question, this answer's example is going to make the OP's head explode. And we don't want to see any brains splattered here.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I agree. I've updated my answer with a hopefully helpful clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `Array` for lists of variable length - use `List<T>` instead - this way you never need to have `null` elements and can use default [`List<T>.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: I **completely missed** that the OP's use case was a variable length collection. +1

Comment: @jdphenix I don't think you should delete your answer - it matches perfectly to question (so it would be useful for someone who really needed that - i.e. manually implementing List-like collection), but in this particular case OP likely would be better with List.